# How can I show all available UPS Shipping methods at once?

Tags: expresso-store

I am trying to add UPS to a store and have it show all the UPS choices in the US and all the International choices automatically for the user. Is there a simple way to add all the UPS choices to the Checkout page?

From what I see it looks I would need to create 10 different UPS plugins each with UPS credentials and then use jQuery to manually switch based off which country the user uses?

Please tell me I am dense and missed something obvious. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You aren't missing anything obvious. It's a design flaw of our shipping plugin system that each installed instance of a shipping plugin can only return a single rate (hence the only way around this currently if you are offering both domestic and international shipping is to create multiple shipping methods using the same plugin).

We're well aware of this issue, and it will be addressed in our next major release. It will require breaking backwards compatibility with some existing checkout templates so not something we can just slip into a point release unfortunately.